# Tutorial tensorflow audio pitch analysis

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, audio, analysis, pitch

I'm a beginner with tensorflow and Python and I'm trying to build an app that automatically detects, in a football (soccer) match some key moments (yellow/red cards, goals, etc).

I'm starting to understand how to do a video analysis training the program on a dataset built by me, downloading images from the web and tagging them. In order to obtain some better results for the analysis, I was wondering if someone had some suggestions on tutorials to follow in order to understand how to train my app also on audio files, to make the program able to understand when there is a pitch variation in the audio of the video and combine both video and audio analysis in order to get better results.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to Python and to tensorflow, I recommend you focus on just audio for now, especially since its a strong indicator of events of importance in a football match (red/yellow cards, nasty fouls, goals, strong chances, good plays, etc).

Very simply, without using much ML at all, you can use the average volume of a time period to infer significance. If you want to get a little more sophisticated, you can consider speech-to-text libraries to look for keywords in commentator speech.

Using video to try to determine when something important is happening is much, much more challenging.

This page can help you get started with audio signal processing in Python.

https://bastibe.de/2012-11-02-real-time-signal-processing-in-python.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll start focusing on this.